# Fields isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, rational-numbers

We know that certain fields has an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ (for example, every ordered field). But, is there an no trivial explicit example of a field that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 5):

You're not gonna find a field that is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ but doesn't "look just like" it: if $K$ is a field isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ and $1_K$ is the identity element, then $\Bbb Z$ uniquely embeds in $K$ by identifying $a\leftrightarrow a\cdot 1_K$. Then the only option for the isomorphism $\Bbb Q\cong K$ is $a/b\leftrightarrow (a\cdot 1_K)/(b\cdot 1_K)$.

Basically the point is that you'll never see a field isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ which the author doesn't just call $\Bbb Q$ because the identification is so "explicit". If you want some trivial answer, you can take any countable set $X$ and use a bijection $\Bbb Q\to X$ to put a field structure on $X$ that will make $X$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ as a field.

Comment: Ok. I understood it. is not last statement false? For example, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is biyectable with $\mathbb{Q}$ but they are not isomorphic fields

Comment: Just because you can take a bijection $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ and use this to put some (emphasize **some**) field structure on $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ doesn't mean that this must be the **same** as the "standard" field structure on $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$.

Comment: Yes. I thought it after writting my last comment